# Inserting Item Collection in Asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, insert

I am trying to insert some words that i keep as an item .My project is asp.net web project.I would like to generate id for each word and keep 4 field null.There are 6 fields in my word table in database.id word length fr Boolean weight.

When I run the project I get this error.

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The
>   connection's current state is closed.

Here the code,

```
 using (con){
    con.Open();

    foreach (var item in results) {//here trying to insert word its id and some other informations but for now they can stay null(yes,null allowed for them)
        id++;
        SqlCommand cmd= con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText= "insert into word values('"+id+"','"+item.Word+"','"+0+"','"+0+"','"+0+"','"+0+"')";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Edit:

I have moved the con.Close out of iteration loop but here now I got this error;

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Incorrect syntax near 's'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character
>   string ')'.

```
 using (con){
        con.Open();

        foreach (var item in results) {//here trying to insert word its id and some other informations but for now they can stay null(yes,null allowed for them)
            id++;
            SqlCommand cmd= con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText= "insert into word values('"+id+"','"+item.Word+"','"+0+"','"+0+"','"+0+"','"+0+"')";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }  con.Close();
}   }
```

Comment: you're closing the connection in every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: I have moved it outside now it gives me this error "Incorrect syntax near 's'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'."

Comment: Can you update your question to include your code as it is now?

Comment: I'd move con.Close(); to a new line. Check the answer posted by @Joe Taras. The full method isn't posted but you probably have an extra closing bracket.

Answer (score 3):

In your code:

```
using (con){
    con.Open();

    foreach (var item in results) {
        //here trying to insert word its id and some other informations but for now they can stay null(yes,null allowed for them)
        id++;
        SqlCommand cmd= con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText= "insert into word values('"+id+"','"+item.Word+"','"+0+"','"+0+"','"+0+"','"+0+"')";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

You have written con.Close() in the foreach, so at the end of the first loop you close your connection.

So move the con.Close() after the close bracket of your foreach like this:

```
using (con){
con.Open();

foreach (var item in results) {//here trying to insert word its id and some other informations but for now they can stay null(yes,null allowed for them)
    id++;
    SqlCommand cmd= con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText= "insert into word values('"+id+"','"+item.Word+"','"+0+"','"+0+"','"+0+"','"+0+"')";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

on first iteration your'e closing the SQL Connection.

move the line: "con.Close();" outside of the loop.

For your second problem, make sure you escape quatation mark in word property
and try using string format to create insert string

```
string word = String.Replace(item.Word,"'","''")
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("insert into word values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')", id, word, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Move con.Close();  outside foreach (){}

Answer (score 1):

You have to be sure that every word (item.Word) has no quotation char, maybe

```
String.Replace(item.Word,"'","''")
```

resolve your problem.